# Photons have no position-space wave function. Do they have a "striking wave function"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

I've been thinking for some time about the possibility of **position**-space representation for **relativistic** quantum particles for some time now, which is something that's often claimed to "not exist" or at least that "any attempt to do it will fail". But I wonder to what extent that is actually true vs. to what extent that's actually more prejudice as to what or how we feel such a representation should look or behave.

And ostensibly, the hardest nut to crack in this sense is the **photon**, because it is perhaps the "ultimate relativistic object": it travels with the most relativistic speed possible - $c$ - at which Newtonian mechanics *completely* goes away and nothing but pure relativity can be used to describe it. And many often say there is no position-space representation at all.

Now, it's *very* well established that a photon has a *momentum*-space representation. *Any* photon can be given a momentum-space wave function $\psi_\mathbf{p}$, which admits a perfectly bog-standard Born rule probability density to be measured as having a given momentum, viz $|\psi_\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{p})|^2$ is the density to have momentum $\mathbf{p}$. Yet, it seems to me that *experiment* shows that nonetheless photons must have "some" kind of affinity for position space because we can do things like seen here:

https://youtu.be/GzbKb59my3U?t=177

(SORRY, I couldn't find the video I wanted that showed them as actual dots on a screen, so this'll have to do...)

where we send them one at a time through a two-slit experiment and have them pile up on the screen one at a time as though they were interfering waves - indeed this is a common textbook claim, and yet it seems with all this "no position representation" stuff floating around it would be on stogy ground!

Now, note that in this experiment, we ostensibly aren't "taking a snapshot" of the photon "while in flight", because the impact with the screen consumes the photon - so right there we're obviously looking at something somewhat different in spirit from non-relativistic quantum theory's "position measurements". But it's still a position-space *something*, and that makes me wonder about this:

Suppose the photon is to be emitted from point $A$ with momentum wave function $\psi_\mathbf{p}$. Is there a method to assign a "**striking probability**" density to absorb it at point $B$, *if* something happens to be there, *and* this method is uniquely or at least "canonically" defined? And moreover, that it can be used, together with some suitable dynamics to incorporate the "slits", to fully mathematically describe the translation to position space required to make sense of that two-slit experiment and observation.

(NOTE: I've dug into some stuff on quantum field theory which turns up the idea of a "propagator" that looks rather like it might have something to do with this, but I am not sure how to use it in this specific way and/or if it will give a unique result.)

(NOTE 2: Presumably we should require that this density, when integrated over a closed surface around $A$, is 1 or at least finite; perhaps this may mean we need to modify it a bit to define it both in terms of $A$ *and* the enclosing surface, to give a density *on that surface*.)

Comment: Have you read the standard works on photon wave functions? John Sipe in 1995 https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.52.1875 and Iwo Bialynicki-Birula has many papers since 1994 https://www.infona.pl/resource/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-appv86z108kz, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0079-6638(08)70316-0, plus all of the papers citing them

Comment: Your 2nd paper is interesting (first is inaccessible). Is the interpretation of that wave function a probability to intercept (i.e. consume) the photon within a region? Then it might make sense. Also, were one to use it to model the given experiment, would one find from it the correct distribution for the impacts to the screen (say, by asking for the probability to be intercepted in small voluminous regions on the screen surface)?

Comment: Something like that - I admit I haven't read the papers in a long time, just wanted to direct you toward them